# $L^p$ space and map $T_h(f)(x)=f(x+h)$ on $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I am trying to show these two statements:

> Let $f \in L^p(\mathbb R^d)$, $1 \leq p < \infty$, then
>
> \begin{align}(a) & \quad  \left(\int_{\mathbb R^d}|f(x-h)-f(x)|^p\,dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \to 0  \text{ when } \|h\| \to 0 \\ 
> (b) & \quad \left(\int_{\mathbb R^d}|f(x-h)+f(x)|^p\,dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \to 2^{\frac{1}{p}}\|f\|_p \text{ when } \|h\| \to \infty 
> \end{align}

I am having some difficulty with this problem.

For (a), it is sufficient to show that $\|f(x+h)-f(x)\|_p^p \to 0 $ when $\|h\| \to 0 $. First I've tried to prove this for continuous functions of compact support. So take $f$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in K^c$ with $K$ a compact set.

Now, $\int_{\mathbb R^d}|f(x-h)-f(x)|^p\,dx=\int_{K^c}|f(x-h)-f(x)|^p\,dx+\int_K|f(x-h)-f(x)|^p\,dx$.

If I could show that for $\|h\|$ sufficiently small, $x-h \in K^c$ for all $x \in K^c$ and $x-h \in K$ for all $x \in K$, then I can use the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $K$ and that $f=0$ on $K^c$ to prove that $\int_{\mathbb R^d}|f(x-h)-f(x)|^p\,dx$ tends to $0$. I don't know what to do to show this.

As for part (b) I am completely lost.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't get $x-h \in K^c$ for all $x\in K^c$. Say $f$ has support in the ball $B_R(0)$. Then for $\lvert h\rvert < 1$, both $x\mapsto f(x-h)$ and $x \mapsto f(x-h) - f(x)$ have support in $B_{R+1}(0)$. For part b), also start with functions with compact support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Suppose first $f$ is continuous with compact support. For (a) note the integral in question is over a fixed bounded set if $|h|<1.$ So the result will hold by the uniform continuity of $f.$ For (b) observe that the supports of $f(x-h), f(x)$ are disjoint for $|h|$ large. Thus the integral equals, exactly, $2^{1/p}\|f\|_p$ for $|h|$ large. For the general $f\in L^p$ use the fact that continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L^p.$

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution. I couldn't understand your answer in (a), why am I integrating over a fixed bounded set with that choice of $||h||$?. As for (b), I would like to choose $||h||$ large enough so that $x-h \not \in K$ for all $x \in K$, where $K$ is the compact support of $f$. If I manage to get this, then $|f(x-h)+f(x)|^p=|f(x-h)|^p+|f(x)|^p$ and I know how to continue from there. I am not sure how to show that if $x \in K \subset B_R(0)$, then there exists some $M$ such that for all $||h||>M$, $x-h$ is not in $K$, could you help me with that?

Comment: Suppose the support of $f$ is contained in $B(0,R)$ and $|h|< 1.$ Then $|x| > R+1 \implies |x-h| \ge |x|-|h|> R,$ hence $ f(x), f(x-h) = 0.$ Thus the integral can be taken over $B(0,R+1)$ for all such $h.$ Note that $|x-h| \ge |h| - |x|.$ This is $> 2R-R = R$ if $|h|>2R, |x|<R.$ This gives disjointness of supports for $|h|>2R.$

Answer (score 1):

This has a very strong flavor of Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem...

In (a), we might say $h_n\longrightarrow0$, and for $f_n(x)=f(x-h_n)$, we have pointwise-a.e. convergence to $f$. Further it shouldn't be too difficult to find a dominating function?

For (b), we can ask what happens to $f_n$ as $h_n\longrightarrow\infty$? In particular, $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ so has to decay to zero at infinity, so as we shift $f_n$ "further away" from $f$, the sum $f_n+f$ should be approaching something that looks like two separate copies of $f$?

Comment: Thanks for the help. So, for (a), since $f$ is continuous, then $|f(x-h_n)-f(x)|^p \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$ for all $x$. Again, using continuity of $f$ and the fact that $f=0$ outside a compact set $K$, let $M=\max\{f(x): x \in \mathbb R^d\}$. Then, we have $|f(x-h_n)-f(x)|^p \leq 2^p(M^p \chi_{K}(x)+|f|^p(x)) \in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$. I know how to finish (a) from here but I am still lost with part (b), I see why $f$ decays to zero at infinity but I don't understand why  "the sum $f_n+f$ should be approaching something that looks like two separate copies of $f$".

Comment: So, using your notation, for a continuous $f$ with compact support, with $h_n\rightarrow\infty$, it will be that $supp(f_n)\subset K^C$ eventually--even the name $T_h$, "translation by $h$", suggests whats happening: if we shift $f$ far enough to, say, $f_n$, then their supports will be disjoint. How will this simplify the integral?

Comment: What do you mean "we might say" in (a)? Also note that there is no dominating function for $(1/\sqrt x)\chi_{(0,1)}$ for the case $p=1$ on the real line. In (b), I'm not sure what you mean by "decay to zero at infinity". Certainly the limit of $f(x)$ as $|x|\to \infty$ need not exist.

Comment: @zhw. : in (a) all I mean is considering the limit as $h$ goes to zero is equivalent to choosing an arbitrary sequence $h_n$ tending to zero, and if we are given a sequence $h_n\rightarrow0$ there is a dominating function that captures all the "spikes" in an integrable manner (the formula in general will be hard to write down, and I cannot see how it won't be an infinite series form, but it should be doable). As far as for (b), the decay at infinity is naturally in an a.e. sense since we are in $L^p$